# Redis-cli not connecting to redis-server

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a redis-server instance running, everything works fine if I try to connect to it via code e.g python. The problem is, `redis-cli` tool doesn't connect. Here's what I get when I run `redis-cli`:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: �
not connected>
```

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: (
not connected>
```

Looking at the response, it's adding some characters after the port, in this case `: �` and `: (`

What could be the problem here? I've also tried `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379` but to no avail.

Note: Redis server is working fine.

Comment: If you've installed it from the repo and played with versions, make sure you do `make distclean && make`

Comment: @ItamarHaber thanks for your reply, I installed it using `apt-get install redis-server`

Comment: Can you use `telnet localhost 6379` and type "PING"+<cr>?

Comment: @ItamarHaber, worked fine, here if what it returned ```telnet localhost 6379
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ping
+PONG```